# Binding textfield text to enable button not working

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, swiftbond

I am new to reactive programming, and Bond framework specifically. I know I may be doing things that are wrong in my basic understanding of this programming technique. This is the situation:

I have a `UITextView` and an "approve" `UIButton`.
I want the approve button to be enabled only when the text in the textView is not nil. I have tried adding these lines of code into my `viewDidLoad` method in my `ViewController`.

```
    textView.reactive.text.observeNext{(text) in
        self.message = text
        print(text)
    }
    textView.reactive.text.map { $0 != nil}.bind(to: approveButtonOutlet.reactive.isEnabled)
```

The first action works (printing the text is happening successfully on every input change). 
The second one does not work, the button is enabled both when the text is not nil and when it is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was that I had a placeholder in my textView, which prevented from the text really being nil. So what eventually I did is this:

```
    textView.reactive.text.map {
        if $0 == placeholder {
            return false
        } else if $0 != nil {
            return $0!.characters.count > 0
        } else{
            return false
        }
        }.bind(to: approveButtonOutlet.reactive.isEnabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like

```
 RAC(self.approveButtonOutlet, enabled) = [self.textView.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
      return @(text.length > 0);
    }];
```

I'm not sure how it will be in swift 3 just try like

```
RAC(self.approveButtonOutlet, enabled) = self.textView.rac_textSignal.map({(text: String) -> void in
    return (text.length > 0)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not understand what RAC is, and it is more important for me to actually understand what is wrong with my solution then getting a different one, since I am trying to learn the framework.. I give you thumbs up for the effort but solving this was also easy just using an if condition on the buttons action